Keeping local outlook contacts up to date with the GAL without relying on users to do it
during last week I studied up MS Graph Powershell and with some trial and error managed to update the contact information of about a 120 or so people, mainly for the purpose of having an up to date phone list that anyone can access from their phone.
The import itself went fine but what I discovered today has shook me to my very core, the contacts I see in the contacts folder in outlook aren't actually synchronized in any way with either the offline GAL or the GAL. I am able to manually update the contacts from the GAL, either individually or by attempting to add them again from the GAL, where I get the option to update all the contacts I selected, a 2 minute task for me, but relying on several hundred people in the company to do this, every time some small piece of info changes is not feasible. (for example, 2 days after the bulk update, I found out that someone had a wrong phone number)
In this thread a MS support person says directly that there is no way to automatically synchronize them, apparently outlook social connector was capable of this but is seemingly deprecated for like a decade now
What I truly need is a way to automate the clicking of this contact update button, for every contact in the a folder (or all folders preferably)
Alternatively, seeing as a I can update contacts by selecting the same contacts in the GAL and importing them, whereupon I get a popup window showing me the changes and giving me the ability to update all, a script which for every contact in a folder imports the contact with the same account name and overwrites it
Has anyone figured out how to do this through a powershell script? Or some sort of office add-in? I've seen that cirasync can seemingly do what I need but I'm a sysadmin junior at this company for all of 6 weeks and I will not be able to convince them to spend that amount of money.
If all fails, I still at least have an up to date GAL, which everyone can always just search through the outlook search bar..
Thanks bunches for any help, this has been driving me up a wall.
I also tried to make a shared folder that I would make sure was kept up to date, it was almost perfect, until the moment I found out that outlook mobile simply does not show you shared contacts, so that's cool :)
